# Merging multiple DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have multiple pairs historical data and i am trying to get their closing prices with the name of the pair and would like to merge them with the matching date and time. This is what i did so far:

```
def load_pairs(arr, period):
    a = arr[0]
    file = '../datas/forex_feed/{} {}.csv'.format(period, a)
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=["Date"], usecols=["Date", "Close"])
    df.rename(columns={'Close':a}, inplace=True)
    for sym in arr:
        if sym == a:
            continue
        file = '../datas/forex_feed/{} {}.csv'.format(period, sym)
        db = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=["Date"], usecols=["Date", "Close"])
        db.rename(columns={'Close':sym}, inplace=True)
        df.join(db)
    print(df.tail())

pairs = 'XAUUSD,XAGUSD,AUDUSD,EURUSD,GBPUSD,EURGBP,EURJPY,GBPJPY,USDCAD,EURCAD,USDCHF,USDZAR,USDJPY,USDTRY,EURTRY,EURAUD,EURCAD,EURCHF,GBPAUD,GBPCAD,GBPCHF,NZDJPY,NZDUSD'
df = load_pairs(pairs.split(','), '15m')

                       XAUUSD
Date                         
2018-09-27 13:15:00  1195.475
2018-09-27 13:30:00  1195.702
2018-09-27 13:45:00  1195.612
2018-09-27 14:00:00  1195.183
2018-09-27 14:15:00  1195.027
```

Somehow it only loads XAUUSD and never merges rest of the files. Below you can find expected output:

```
                       XAUUSD      XAGUSD      AUDUSD
Date                         
2018-09-27 13:15:00  1195.475    14.74500     0.71548
2018-09-27 13:30:00  1195.702    14.74512     0.715
2018-09-27 13:45:00  1195.612    14.74572     0.71501
2018-09-27 14:00:00  1195.183    14.74608     0.71595
2018-09-27 14:15:00  1195.027    14.74501     0.71570
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try with `df = df.join(db)`. Please refer [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join)

Comment: This gives me following error: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['EURCAD'], dtype='object') in one file. Rest of them works great

Comment: The error is because you have EURCAD twice in your variable `pairs`.

Comment: ah thank you very much!!!